# Cannot access variable within nested ask block in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to set an "attractiveness" variable to patches within a specific radius ("path radius", dependent on the length of the turtle) of a turtle. "Attractiveness" is modeled as exponential decay and is dependent on the distance of each patch to the turtle and the patch radius. Below is the code that I have used. Everything works well but when I set the "patch_attractiveness", I get a "division by zero" error. This is because within the ask "open_patches_in_radius" block, "patch_radius" is set to zero when it shouldn't. I'm not sure why it is 0, when I would expect a "patch_radius is undefined" error if anything. I have also tried setting "patch_radius" as a global variable, in case I am unable to access it within the "ask patches" block because I define it in the "ask turtle" block. How else can I achieve what I want?

```
patches-own [
distance_to_fish
patch_radius
patch_attractiveness
]

turtles-own [
fish_length
]


to hatch_fish
  create-turtles (random 2) [
        set fish_length 15
  ]
end

to find_potential_destination_cells

ask turtles [

let my_patch self

set patch_radius ((50 * (fish_length ^ 2)) / 100) / resolution 

let open_patches_in_radius patches in-radius patch_radius
    
ask open_patches_in_radius [

      set distance_to_fish ([distance myself] of my_patch)
      set patch_attractiveness exp ((distance_to_fish / patch_radius) * (log e (.2 / 1)))

    ]
]
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netlogo, variables always start out with a value of zero, which indicates that the value of patch_radius has not been changed for some of the patches involved.

In the current setup, each patch has a `patch_radius` of 0 except for the patch that the turtle is standing on, since that is the only patch whose variable the turtle can change. This got me thinking that it does not really make a lot of sense to have `patch_radius` be `patches-own` variable since it is a variable that only the turtle is using. Making it a `turtles-own` variable thus makes a lot more sense. I would personally even consider a local variable, using `let`, since it is only used within this one procedure and doesn't have to be preserved in between procedures/ticks from what I can see.

The next part is that you ask all the `open_patches_in_radius` to do something with `patch_radius` but you don't define whose patch_radius they should work with, so they all take their own patch_radius. This variable is still 0 since we didn't set it to anything else.

There are two more errors I found in your code: you use let `my_patch self` in a turtle context, which means that the variable `my_patch` is now a turtle.
Later in the code your turtle asks the `open_patches_in_radius` to
`set distance_to_fish ([distance myself] of my_patch)`. Since my-patch was defined as the turtle who called it, and that same turtle is then referred to by the use of `myself`, `distance_to_fish` is just the distance from a turtle to itself and will always be 0. As I see no reason to define `my_patch`, you could just use `set distance_to_fish distance myself` which does give you the distance between the patch and the turtle.

Patch_radius as a turtles-own variable with give this code:

```
patches-own [
   distance_to_fish
   patch_attractiveness
]

turtles-own [
   fish_length
   patch_radius
]

to find_potential_destination_cells

   ask turtles [

   set patch_radius ((50 * (fish_length ^ 2)) / 100) / resolution 
   let open_patches_in_radius patches in-radius patch_radius
    
   ask open_patches_in_radius [
      set distance_to_fish distance myself
      set patch_attractiveness exp ((distance_to_fish / [patch_radius] of myself) * (log e (.2 / 1)))
      ]
   ]
 end
```

Patch_radius as a local variable would give

```
to find_potential_destination_cells

   ask turtles [

   let patch_radius ((50 * (fish_length ^ 2)) / 100) / resolution 
   let open_patches_in_radius patches in-radius patch_radius
    
   ask open_patches_in_radius [
      set distance_to_fish distance myself
      set patch_attractiveness exp ((distance_to_fish / patch_radius) * (log e (.2 / 1)))
      ]
   ]
 end
```

Comment: thanks! where is "my_patch" defined though? before the "patch_radius" is set?

Comment: Oops, looks like I was a bti too quick with copypasting. I just completely removed `my_patch.`
If you still want to include it, you could use `let my_patch patch-here`. That would allow you to see what patch the turtle came from and is useful if you want to calculate the distances between two patches rather than the distance between a patch and a turtle, if that is what your model requires.